# Rendering an Obj file with implicit face normals

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, render, rajawali

I'm trying to render a submarine object from [poly](https://poly.google.com/view/8PgPdFGg3MO), the 3d object consists from obj file and a png texture file.

In this specific submarine object the vertex normal indices are implicit. You can see it when looking on the "faces" lines, for example:
`f 40/91 41/90 37/89 36/88`

I tried to use [rajawali](http://%20https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali) to render the object, but I get a runtime exception
`there are no normals specified for this model.`

It looks like `rajawali` expect for **explicit declaration of face normals**, although:

> Vertices are stored in a counter-clockwise order by default, making explicit declaration of face normals unnecessary.
>   from [.obj wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

I aware that when you work with a 3D graphics software, one can just check the "Include Normals" checkbox, as described for example [here](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/issues/740#issuecomment-18009065).
But I'm trying to work with **objects from [Poly](https://poly.google.com/)**, and currently, I didn't found a robust engine that succeeds to render at least most of the objects in Poly.

My questions are:
1. How can I render this object, and similar ones, that has implicit face normals?
2. Is there a robust 3D **android** rendering engine, so the large library of 3D objects in Poly can be useful in android?